# i want to print every slot of my array at a new line

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

this is my current code , i have to print every world of my name on a new line

```
include "stdafx.h"
#include "iostream"
#include "string"
using namespace std;
int main ()
{
    string a;
    char j[100];
    int i, c, b; 
    cout <<"enter your full  name ";
        getline(cin,a);
        cout << " ur name is " << a << endl;
c=a.size(); 
for (b=0; b<=c; b++)
{
j[b]=a[b];
j[b]='\0';
}
system ("pause");
return 0; 
}
```

how can i print every part of my name  on a new line ? ex : input : geroge ashley mark . output : george (newline) ashley (newline) mark

Comment: You used the thing that makes new lines in your code so I'm really confused by your question.

Comment: Why are you even copying into an array (and doing it wrong to begin with)?

Comment: because the users name might be composed not single . so i dont want to put more than 1 cin

Comment: Can you give an example of the input and expected output?

Comment: Checkout http://stackoverflow.com/questions/236129/split-a-string-in-c (it is even part of the C++ FAQ)

Comment: input : george adam ashley output : george adam ashley but each word on a different line

Comment: @RidaHelbawi _"input : george ..."_ [Add this information to your question please](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/27405752/edit). That also gives you the opportunity to show how it exactly looks like (including newlines etc.)

Answer (score 0):

This is a little convoluted way to do this, I prefer the method shown in the comments. However, if you want to avoid stringstreams, here is another way to achieve what you are looking for. It will also support comma separated names.

```
#include "stdafx.h"

#include "iostream"
#include "string"
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    string a;
    char j[100];
    int i, c, b;
    cout << "enter your full  name ";
    getline(cin, a);
    cout << " ur name is " << a << endl;
    c = a.size();

    bool space = false;

    for (auto iter = a.begin(); iter != a.end(); iter++)
    {
        if (isalpha(*iter) == false)
        {
            if (space == false)
            {
                cout << std::endl;
                space = true;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            cout << (*iter);
            space = false;
        }
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: *how can i print every part of my name on a new line ?* I dont think OP wants one char per line.